# Does startService() create a new Service instance or using the existing one?

Tags: android

Does startService() create a new Service instance or using the existing one?
For example, in the following code, does it create two UpdateService instances or just one UpdateService instance?
Thanks.

```
    int[] appWidgetIds = new int[] {1, 2};  
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If the service is already started, it does not start as second copy, but `onStart()` is still called on the existing instance. Services are natural singletons -- there is exactly 0 or 1 copy of the service in operation.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare I upvoted your question, every time I see your answer, its most easier to understand and I found helpful and upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 15):

The `onStart` method is deprecated for now, use `onStartCommand` instead.