# Pass data from Activity to Service using an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service

How do I get data within an Android `Service` that was passed from an invoking `Activity`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**First Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

For Service, you need to override onStartCommand there you have direct access to `intent`:

```
Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
```

You have a few options:

1) Use the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) from the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

3) Use the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) shortcut method of the Intent

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

**New Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this getter is just for example purpose, can differ
if (myIntent !=null && myIntent.getExtras()!=null)
     String value = myIntent.getExtras().getString(key);
}
```

***NOTE:*** Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types, Parcelables, and Serializables. I just used Strings for demonstrational purposes.

Comment: But we can't use getIntent() method inside a service. How can achieve this when we are sending value from activity to service?

Comment: just use intent no getIntent() is required

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, as this is not the correct solution for services.

Answer (score 236):

For a precise answer to this question on "How to send data via intent from an Activity to Service", Is that you have to override the `onStartCommand()` method which is where you receive the intent object:

When you create a `Service` you should override the `onStartCommand()` method so if you closely look at the signature below, this is where you receive the `intent` object which is passed to it:

```
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

So from an activity you will create the intent object to start service and then you place your data inside the intent object for example you want to pass a `UserID` from `Activity` to `Service`:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourService.class.getName())
 serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
 context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

When the service is started its `onStartCommand()` method will be called so in this method you can retrieve the value (UserID) from the intent object for example

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String userID = intent.getStringExtra("UserID");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Note: the above answer specifies to get an Intent with `getIntent()` method which is not correct in context of a service

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. The accepted answer is wrong for Service.

Comment: I have this error : `Unable to start service Intent: not found`

Comment: getintent  is now depricated

Comment: How do I send an intent to the service after service has started?

Comment: So you can only access the variable inside of the onStartCommand function in your service? That makes it pretty useless doesnt it?

Answer (score 10):

If you bind your service, you will get the Extra in `onBind(Intent intent)`.

Activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);                                                                                     
 intent.putExtra("tour_name", mTourName);                    
 bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Service:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    mTourName = intent.getStringExtra("tour_name");
    return mBinder;
}
```

Comment: @ChefPharaoh that's a good question. Try to log the intent's values. `Arrays.toString(yourAry[])` will help you here.

Comment: Since I wanted to pass a custom class I figured out I just had to implement the parcelable interface and the it was all good. Thanks though.

Answer (score 7):

Another posibility is using intent.getAction:

In Service:

```
public class SampleService inherits Service{
    static final String ACTION_START = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.ACTION_START";
    static final String ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1 = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.DO_SOMETHING_1";
    static final String ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_2 = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.DO_SOMETHING_2";
    static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.STOP_SERVICE";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        //System.out.println("ACTION: "+action);
        switch (action){
            case ACTION_START:
                startingService(intent.getIntExtra("valueStart",0));
                break;
            case ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1:
                int value1,value2;
                value1=intent.getIntExtra("value1",0);
                value2=intent.getIntExtra("value2",0);
                doSomething1(value1,value2);
                break;
            case ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_2:
                value1=intent.getIntExtra("value1",0);
                value2=intent.getIntExtra("value2",0);
                doSomething2(value1,value2);
                break;
            case ACTION_STOP_SERVICE:
                stopService();
                break;
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void startingService(int value){
        //calling when start
    }

    public void doSomething1(int value1, int value2){
        //...
    }

    public void doSomething2(int value1, int value2){
        //...
    }

    public void stopService(){
        //...destroy/release objects
        stopself();
    }
}
```

In Activity:

```
public void startService(int value){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(SampleService.ACTION_START);
    myIntent.putExtra("valueStart",value);
    startService(myIntent);
}

public void serviceDoSomething1(int value1, int value2){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(SampleService.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1);
    myIntent.putExtra("value1",value1);
    myIntent.putExtra("value2",value2);
    startService(myIntent);
}

public void serviceDoSomething2(int value1, int value2){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(SampleService.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_2);
    myIntent.putExtra("value1",value1);
    myIntent.putExtra("value2",value2);
    startService(myIntent);
}

public void endService(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(SampleService.STOP_SERVICE);
    startService(myIntent);
}
```

Finally, In Manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".SampleService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.ACTION_START"/>
        <action android:name="com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.DO_SOMETHING_1"/>
        <action android:name="com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.DO_SOMETHING_2"/>
        <action android:name="com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.STOP_SERVICE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: You are starting the service multiple times...does that mean multiple instances of the same service wil be created every time ?

Comment: Services have singleton pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518238/does-startservice-create-a-new-service-instance-or-using-the-existing-one

Comment: "switch (action)" action can be null

Comment: Not in my code: The service is always called using a method. In any case, it's a simple code to explain how to do it. In a real program, you always have to check these things and also if the parameters arrive with the appropriate values

Answer (score 3):

Activity:

```
int number = 5;
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
i.putExtra("MyNumber", number);
startService(i);
```

Service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null){
        int number = intent.getIntExtra("MyNumber", 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pass data from Activity to IntentService

This is how I pass data from `Activity` to `IntentService`.

One of my [application](https://github.com/rohitksingh/OLA_Play_Music_App) has this scenario.

#### MusicActivity ------url(String)------> DownloadSongService

**1) Send Data (Activity code)**

```
  Intent intent  = new Intent(MusicActivity.class, DownloadSongService.class);
  String songUrl = "something"; 
  intent.putExtra(YOUR_KEY_SONG_NAME, songUrl);
  startService(intent);
```

**2) Get data in Service (IntentService code)**
You can access the intent in the `onHandleIntent()` method

```
public class DownloadSongService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        String songUrl = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY_SONG_NAME");

        //  Download File logic
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### This is a much better and secured way. Working like a charm!

```
   private void startFloatingWidgetService() {
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,FloatingWidgetService.class)
                .setAction(FloatingWidgetService.ACTION_PLAY));
    }
```

instead of :

```
 private void startFloatingWidgetService() {
        startService(new Intent(FloatingWidgetService.ACTION_PLAY));
    }
```

Because when you try 2nd one then you get an error saying :
***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.floatingwidgetchathead_demo.SampleService.ACTION_START }***

Then your Service be like this :

```
static final String ACTION_START = "com.floatingwidgetchathead_demo.SampleService.ACTION_START";
    static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.floatingwidgetchathead_demo.SampleService.ACTION_PLAY";
    static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.floatingwidgetchathead_demo.SampleService.ACTION_PAUSE";
    static final String ACTION_DESTROY = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.SampleService.ACTION_DESTROY";

 @SuppressLint("LogConditional")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    //System.out.println("ACTION: "+action);
    switch (action){
        case ACTION_START:
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+action);
            break;
        case ACTION_PLAY:
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+action);
           addRemoveView();
           addFloatingWidgetView();
            break;
        case ACTION_PAUSE:
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+action);
            break;
        case ACTION_DESTROY:
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+action);
            break;
    }
    return START_STICKY;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Service: startservice can cause side affects,best way to use messenger and pass data.

```
private CallBackHandler mServiceHandler= new CallBackHandler(this);
private Messenger mServiceMessenger=null;
//flag with which the activity sends the data to service
private static final int DO_SOMETHING=1;

private static class CallBackHandler extends android.os.Handler {

private final WeakReference<Service> mService;

public CallBackHandler(Service service) {
    mService= new WeakReference<Service>(service);
}

public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    //Log.d("CallBackHandler","Msg::"+msg);
    if(DO_SOMETHING==msg.arg1)
    mSoftKeyService.get().dosomthing()
}
}
```

Activity:Get Messenger from Intent fill it pass data and pass the message back to service

```
private Messenger mServiceMessenger;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mServiceMessenger = (Messenger)extras.getParcelable("myHandler");
}


private void sendDatatoService(String data){
Intent serviceIntent= new 
Intent(BaseActivity.this,Service.class);
Message msg = Message.obtain();
msg.obj =data;
msg.arg1=Service.DO_SOMETHING;
mServiceMessenger.send(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin you can try the following code,

In the sending activity,

```
  val intent = Intent(context, RecorderService::class.java);
  intent.putExtra("filename", filename);
  context.startService(intent)
```

In the service,

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

    if (intent != null && intent.extras != null)
       val filename = intent.getStringExtra("filename")

}
```