# Web Server: use Service instead of Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-service

I wrote an app that implements a web server with multithreading.
The main activity has a button to start/stop a thread. When the server is powered on, this thread stays in listening and, if there is a request it creates a new thread to serve it.
The app works fine, but now I would use a service instead, so it can work in background.

Actually I've this design (semplified):

**WebServer.java**

```
class WebServer implements Runnable{
protected Thread t;

 public void start(){
  ON=true;
  t=new Thread(this,"WebServer");
  t.start();
 }

 public void stop(){
 ON=false;
 t=null;}

 public void run(){
 while(ON)
 ...
 }

 public isOn(){
  return ON;
 }
}
```

**DroidServer.java**

```
class DroidServer extends WebServer{
...
}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
ws = new DroidServer(8080,this);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View V){
    if(!ws.isOn()){
     ws.start();
     btn.setText("Stop");
    }else{
     ws.stop();
     btn.setText("Start");
    }}});
}
```

What should I change, to make it use Services? I'd like to extends Service from DroidServer, but this class already extends WebServer... any solutions?

Comment: Hm... I saw a question very similar to this one, but I can't look for it right now. Here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service is not a replacement for a Thread. 
Per definition from [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) :

> Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what
>   it is not:
>
> - A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself
>     does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise
>     specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part
>     of.
>
>   A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off
>     of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

What you should do it create a Service then have your DroidServer run in the Service as a separate Thread so it could accept request in the background

Comment: Hm.. I've a doubt: In this way (with a service that creates a thread), could Android System destroy this thread? Or is it "protected" by the Service?

Comment: No, you should control how the Thread is stopped similar to what you did in your Activity. A Service is just basically just a way for Android to facilitate background process (i.e application process without user's interaction)

Comment: Ok! Can I pass parameters to the Service? In my case the activity passes a reference of itself to DroidServer `ws = new DroidServer(8080,this);`

Comment: Yes, you could pass the parameter via Intent as this question illustrate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll do as you suggested