# Exception while passing extras through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass a string from 1 activity to another, although I have taken reference from many accepted answers from other threads, I am facing problem that I am not able to debug. When I comment extras.putString as shown in code below, Toast message shows the correct address which means value is being set properly and code works fine but when I use extras.putString(), I get NullPointerException and application closes due to exception.  There are many \n characters in my address string. Infact even if I use extras.putString("userAddress", "test") I get NullPointerException

Here is my Main Activity from which I want to call FBShare Activity:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, FBShare.class);   
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
String currentAddress = getCurrentAddress(ourLocation);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCurrentAddress(ourLocation), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
extras.putString("userAddress", currentAddress);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

And in FBShare Activity I am trying to fetch values as follows

```
strAddress = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userAddress");
```

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent) one thread which is doing similar thing.

Comment: look at @akki's answer, you're missing the `mIntent.putExtras(extras);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try my code

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, FBShare.class);   
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
String currentAddress = getCurrentAddress(ourLocation);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCurrentAddress(ourLocation), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
extras.putString("userAddress", currentAddress);
mIntent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Try directly putting extra on the intent:

`mIntent.putExtra("Key", "Value")`

Also, you retrieve the extra using

```
Intene t = getIntent();
String k="key";
if (t.hasExtra(k)) {
  s = t.getStringExtra(k);
  ...
}
```

The are get/put for many var types

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, FBShare.class);   
String currentAddress = getCurrentAddress(ourLocation);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getCurrentAddress(ourLocation), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
mIntent.putString("userAddress", currentAddress);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Bundle is not need in your case because it seems that you are only pasing a string you can use the above code..