# Pass information to a android service

Tags: android, service, parameters

I have a service in android, and I need to pass parameters to it..I have no idea how to do it..

I tried to putExtra but it wasn't an intent...I used constructor but it doesn't work with constructors..

Comment: this link might be helpful for you.  
[link]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent

Comment: @user1050389 see the solution posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
intent.putExtra("someKey", someData);
intent.putExtra("anotherKey", anotherData);
startService(intent);
```

In YourService :

```
public void onStartCommand(Intent data, int startId, int flags) {
    int data1 = data.getExtra("someKey");
    int data2 = data.getExtra("anotherKey");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can I used startService() instead of startActivity()?

Comment: Thank you! Oh and, if I want to call a retrieve information back from the service, how can I do that?

Comment: @user1050389 see this link for that : [ http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/ ]

Answer (score 0):

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String[] info = intent.getStringArrayExtra("information");
}
```