# Should I modify sync function to a Android Service?

Tags: android

I used to  develope  a component as  sync data functions.  Now  I  want  to  modify it  as  android  service .  But this function  have  to  use  activity variable .  I cannot  deliever  "activity" variable  to a  service . So  I'm  getting  confuse  now .  What  can I do with  it  now ? Or  what  better  solution  maybe?

Comment: As geet said. Give an example of what your doing. The service class also extends context so has some of the same functions available.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value of variable declared in your activity to your service using Intents. Here is a very good explanation on this topic [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent)