# How to show different Message with each Notification android?

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an android app in which i want to show a new message in the Notification Bar with each new notification. I am able to show notificaitions at specific time but i want to show each notification with a differnent Message.

Below i am pasting smaple code that shows two notifications at the specified time.
I have used the Alarm manager class to show the notifications .
**MainActivity**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

     calendar.setTime(new Date(formattedDate1));
     calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
     calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
     calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);


    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);       

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("myIntent", "Notification1");
    myIntent.setType("intent1");
    pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
            myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent1);

    Calendar calendar_new = Calendar.getInstance();

    // calendar_new.setTime(new Date(, month, day))

    calendar_new.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar_new.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 12);
    calendar_new.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent myIntentnew = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    myIntentnew.setType("intent2");
    myIntentnew.putExtra("myIntentnew", "Notification2");
    pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1,
            myIntentnew, 0);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar_new.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent2);


} // end onCreate
```

**Notification Service**

```
private NotificationManager mManager;
Notification notification;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(
                    this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());


    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "We succeded", "hi!", pendingNotificationIntent);

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    mManager.cancelAll();
}
```

If anybody could help me with this . Thanks in advance

Comment: "I want to show each notification with a differnent Message." What do you mean by this? You are generating notification hardcoded or getting it from server??

Comment: for now i am generating hardcoded,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 mManager.notify(0, notification);
```

to

```
  mManager.notify(count , notification);
```

where count increase every time by 1 .

```
   mManager.notify(0, notification)
```

replace message every time

```
   Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourService.class.getName())
   serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
   context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

When the service is started its onStartCommand() method will be called so in this method you can retrieve the value (UserID) from the intent object for example

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

String userID = intent.getStringExtra("UserID");

return START_STICKY;
  }
```

Comment: I did try your solution but its not showing new message and as an update i passing static date values in here and static message but once i am able to show new message i will fetch the new message from database .

Comment: I tried out your solution it is showing the first message but for the next time interval it gives an null pointer Exception. Any Idea about that.?? I am passing my custom messages with intent in MainActivity, the code for which i have shown above

Comment: can u get data from  onStartCommand() ? override this in your service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent

Comment: yes i am able to get data from onStartCommand(), i have also solved the NullPointerException but still i am not able to show custom message in the second notification

Answer (score 1):

You can change this mManager.notify(0, notification); to  mManager.notify((int) when, notification);

where long when = System.currentTimeMillis();