# Connection between Activity and Service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I have an Activity with an EditText and some checkboxes. After the user inserts a text the text should be sent to the Service and the Service will run in background showing a Toast from time to time.

I am having a really hard time trying to figure out **how to send the data**(Strings and Boolean values that user inputs through the Activity)  **to the Service** .

Comment: What is the function of the Service? Is it to communicate over the network?

Comment: The Service simply shows a Toast from time to time, even after the user closes the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Intent on Activity put values in puExtra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, YourClass.class);
intent.putextra("keyName","value");
```

and then call StartService so the OnStart method call be called.. 
in service get the values in OnStart by using intent

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) 
   {
     String value = extras.getString("key");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Android Documentation For Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)?

It explains everything you need to know and more :)

(hint: you must pass an Intent to OnStartCommand())

If you google "pass an intent to a service in android" among the first results you'll find:

[Pass data from Activity to Service using an Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent)

Comment: You have the option to use SharedPreferences too. Might be an easier way for the OP to get started as there's less involved and somewhat more intuitive.

Comment: mbs Do you know an example of the SharedPreferences usage? Thanks

Comment: Martin Marconcini i took a look but it's pointing me exactly where i want to. Reading you link right now, thanks you