# Passing a Socket type parameter to background service?

Tags: java, android, sockets

From the main activity of an android application, is it possible pass a Socket type parameter to a service upon starting the service?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that:

1. Use [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable) to store your socket instance, then in your service, just call it

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {
      private static Socket socket;
      public Socket getSocket() {
       return socket;
      }

      public void setSomeVariable(Socket otherSocket) {
       this.socket = otherSocket;
      }
   }
   ```
2. Use [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3293536/719212) to pass and receive data field by field (or can use serializable or [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)). But this way will create other instance of socket
3. Use [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to send and receive from activity to service

Comment: How would you call it in the service?