# Timing of using android IPC mechanisms

Tags: android-service, android-contentprovider, android-service-binding, android-backup-service, android-handlerthread

There are several methods to do IPC in Android - Content Provider, Message, AIDL, Async Task, IntentService ...

Seems like each of them aims to solve particular problem.

How to decide which I should use?

I need a service keep running in background, at the same time other services or activity may acquire data from this service.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a service keeps running in the background, I think you should try to implement a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent) for data exchange between activity and service.