# How to best do this in android?

Tags: java, android, aide-ide

I am thinking of making an app that interacts with a Web API.

**Requirement:**

1. Start the bet and Display notification
2. Send the bet to the site via POST.
3. When the result arrives, update UI with the result.
4. If the user hasn't pressed the stop button, back to #2 else stop the bet and remove notification.
5. If the app is closed or not the active app, the betting would still continue
6. If the notification is clicked, show/start the app

After a lot of research and reading, I thought that the bound foreground service would accomplish this, but I can't find (or maybe I just don't understand) how doing it...

**Here are my questions:**

If I make a service and put the logic of betting in it, my activity/app would start the service and bind with it..

1. How can I tell the service to start betting with the initial bet data from the activity?
2. How can the service know when the app closes or is not the active app on screen?
3. How can the service update the UI of the app?

I will still search for a possible way to do this. I hope someone can guide me to the right way..

**Update**

(3) I ended up using `LocalBroadcast` to signal the App components from the service of when to update the UI.

(2) By using `LocalBroadcast`, I thought that my service should not mind the my App's State.

(1) I used `Bound Service` and just call method on the service to pass data and start betting.

Comment: -ve voters, he is asking for clarification and guidance...

Comment: Whe downvote?  Atleast tell me the reason for the downvote...

Comment: Try reading the documentation @ https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @KaryuuOuji this is an enigma which no one can sort out, may be some pundits find themselves unable to answer so they dislike questions..

Comment: @Faisal maybe your right... I will try anything I can think of right now and maybe ask another question when needed be... I still am searching for possible way to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send data to service via Intent: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15899750/3423468

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourService.class.getName());
serviceIntent.putExtra("data", "123456");
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Then in Service override `OnStartCommand` method:

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
   String userID = intent.getStringExtra("data");
   return START_STICKY;//or non-sticky
}
```

For handling app close event you can check this answer(never used myself):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26882533/3423468

And regarding your last question, you can [use `BroadcastReciever` to send data from service to activity and update UI](https://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/)

For further reading check this links:

1. [Services Tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)
2. [Official Developers Guide To Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)
3. [BroadCastReceivers Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)

Comment: Thanks... I will be trying this out and re-read those articles you linked..  Most of the articles in Android Developer site is a bit hard for me to understand thoroughly...

Comment: Take a look and ask me if you need anything. I'd give you my own examples but can't write in Java well, I'm Xamarin developer.

Comment: does listeners work for service? Im thinking of giving my service a listener that my activity will implement and pass data through that event..

Comment: By listener You mean `BroadcastReceiver` or an interface?

Comment: an interface ... I think the Binder is what I am looking for, I missed that part while reading #2 link... I am currently studying it now...

Comment: Any progress on the issue?

Comment: I haven't implemented this yet, nor started coding, coz my whole project got deleted accedentally by my mother... Im redoing my project now and nearly on this part...

Comment: that's sad, comment if you need anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use volley api.
Add it as a dependent in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```