# Android Intent QUestions

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I'm currenly doing this when i clicked a button

```
    Intent service = new Intent(this, LocationCheckingService.class);
        startService(service);
```

if i where to click this button multiple times does it result in multiple thread being invoked? possible to prevent multiple service? cause i would only require one service

Comment: @user492182 consider initializing a flag isServiceStarted to false and setting the flag to true once you call startService and then check this flag before calling startService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run multiple instances of a Service: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#StartingAService

Answer (score 0):

there can be only one instace of service. no matter how many times you starts
see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692915/create-only-one-instance-of-service-android/3692966#3692966)

Comment: oh so it means it's only one service will be started? if it's recalled again oncreate wont be call but only onstart rite