# Android duplicate services

Tags: android, android-service

I was wondering if a service (myService.class) can be created twice(or more) when using the same class. for example if the first initiation is on Application (which means it keeps running on the background) and the others happens on broadcast received

```
 startService(new Intent(this, myService.class));
```

or if the service is currently running then the others are not initialize..?

Answer (score 4):

as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692915/create-only-one-instance-of-service-android), Service has a single instance. and as it stated on the docs every call to startService makes corresponding instance of the service onStartCommand to be invoked. But doesnt create a new instance.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong - if it is on different context it is possible, but if I use the same context(getApplicationContext() for example)  then only one instance is created, right?

Comment: no, afaik this is per application - that is per package

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution for this.

Whenever the `startService()` is called, `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()` are also called. But the variables are still the same and are not initialized again.

So, to tackle this, create a private field like:

```
private var isRunning = false
```

or:

```
private boolean isRunning = false;
```

Then, in `onCreate()`:

```
    if (!isRunning) {
        Log.i("ServiceStarter", "On start called")
        isRunning = true
        // do your work here
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what they are talking about up in this thread but my service sure was being instantiated many times. Your solution works like a charm!