# Android - Get bound service and shut it down

Tags: android

Is there any way to get a list of all services bound to an application?
It seems there has been cases where my application does not close the service when it should. It works fine when I test it but I've seen cases where it does not seem to close. Which results in two services when there should only be one.

I use this code to bind the service from my activity.

```
bindService(new Intent(this, XmppService.class), xmppConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Is there any way of getting a reference to this bound service and shut it down?

Comment: I don't think, there is a way to do this. But have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3692966/4791726). There will only be one instance of a service. I don't think you will have two running instances of one service.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm gonna try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15020748/1245158) answer. That could help. It will probably take some time before I can verify the results though.

Comment: Didn't seem to help much with my issue unfortunately.